# Group by and 'normalize' if the sum of the groups exceeds a threshold with defined decimal numbers

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data set where I group by `element` and `date`, then round to 6 decimal places and 'normalize' to get the sum equal to 1. I have the following dataframe:

```py
data = {'element': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
        'subelement': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1','B2', 'B3','B4', 'B5','B5', 'B7', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
        'date': ['2022-06-01', '2022-06-01', '2022-06-01', '2022-06-01', '2022-06-01', '2022-06-01',
                 '2022-06-01','2022-06-01', '2022-06-01', '2022-06-01','2022-07-01','2022-07-01','2022-07-01'],
        'factor_a': [0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
                    0.142857142857143, 0.142857142857143, 0.142857142857143, 0.142857142857143,
                    0.142857142857143, 0.142857142857143, 0.142857142857143,
                   0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333],
        'factor_b': [0.65, 0.35, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I tried following, which after normalization the sum is still `0.999999` or `1.000001`.

```py
cols = df.columns[3:]
groups = df.groupby(['element', 'date'])[cols] 
sum_ = groups.transform('sum')
df[cols+'_norm'] = (df[cols] / sum_).round(6)
```

Expected outcome:

| element | subelement | date | factor_a | factor_b | factor_a_norm | factor_b_norm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | 2022-06-01 | 0.333333333333333 | 0.65 | 0.333333 | 0.650000 |
| A | A2 | 2022-06-01 | 0.333333333333333 | 0.35 | 0.333333 | 0.350000 |
| A | A3 | 2022-06-01 | 0.333333333333333 | 0.00 | 0.333334 | 0.000000 |
| B | B1 | 2022-06-01 | 0.142857142857143 | 0.50 | 0.142857 | 0.500000 |
| B | B2 | 2022-06-01 | 0.142857142857143 | 0.50 | 0.142857 | 0.500000 |
| B | B3 | 2022-06-01 | 0.142857142857143 | 0.00 | 0.142857 | 0.000000 |
| B | B4 | 2022-06-01 | 0.142857142857143 | 0.00 | 0.142857 | 0.000000 |
| B | B5 | 2022-06-01 | 0.142857142857143 | 0.00 | 0.142857 | 0.000000 |
| B | B6 | 2022-06-01 | 0.142857142857143 | 0.00 | 0.142857 | 0.000000 |
| B | B7 | 2022-06-01 | 0.142857142857143 | 0.00 | 0.142858 | 0.000000 |
| C | C1 | 2022-07-01 | 0.333333333333333 | 0.333333333333333 | 0.333333 | 0.333333 |
| C | C2 | 2022-07-01 | 0.333333333333333 | 0.333333333333333 | 0.333333 | 0.333333 |
| C | C3 | 2022-07-01 | 0.333333333333333 | 0.333333333333333 | 0.333334 | 0.333334 |

I would like to get the sum to equal 1 with 6 decimal places for each group. Is there any way to get this?

Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple idea
just normalize the normalized `factor_a_norm`

```
normalized_arr = preprocessing.normalize([factor_a_norm])
```

Comment: Here i am using from sklearn import preprocessing
you will get the desired result

Comment: I want to get `factor_a_norm` and `factor_b_norm`, i.e, adjust to 1 if the sum is not exact. Preprocessing normalize method is to scale the feature which is not my objective.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your current code and further correct with:

```
s = df.groupby(['element', 'date'])[cols+'_norm'].transform('sum').rsub(1)

df.loc[~df.duplicated(['element', 'date'], keep='last')] += s
```

Output:

```
    element subelement        date  factor_a  factor_b  factor_a_norm  factor_b_norm
0        A         A1  2022-06-01  0.333333  0.650000       0.333333       0.650000
1        A         A2  2022-06-01  0.333333  0.350000       0.333333       0.350000
2        A         A3  2022-06-01  0.333333  0.000000       0.333334       0.000000
3        B         B1  2022-06-01  0.142857  0.500000       0.142857       0.500000
4        B         B2  2022-06-01  0.142857  0.000000       0.142857       0.000000
5        B         B3  2022-06-01  0.142857  0.500000       0.142857       0.500000
6        B         B4  2022-06-01  0.142857  0.000000       0.142857       0.000000
7        B         B5  2022-06-01  0.142857  0.000000       0.142857       0.000000
8        B         B5  2022-06-01  0.142857  0.000000       0.142857       0.000000
9        B         B7  2022-06-01  0.142857  0.000000       0.142858       0.000000
10       C         C1  2022-07-01  0.333333  0.333333       0.333333       0.333333
11       C         C2  2022-07-01  0.333333  0.333333       0.333333       0.333333
12       C         C3  2022-07-01  0.333333  0.333333       0.333334       0.333334
```